# How to check the compactness of these sets:

Tags: metric-spaces

How to check the compactness of these sets:

a.the unit sphere in $l_2$ the space of all square summable real sequences with its usual metric i.e.$d({x_i,y_i}) =(\sum_1^\infty|x_i-y_i|^2)^{1/2}$

b.the closure of the unit ball.

I find many equivalent conditions on compact sets but dont know which to use

Comment: Each set contains the standard unit vectors. Does this set have a limit point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closed unit ball is not compact in any infinite dimensional Banach space. Thus the closure of unit ball is not compact.
If the unit sphere in $\ell_2 $ were compact then the sequence $\{e_n\}$ of vectors of orthogonal basis of $\ell_2$ should has a convergent subsequence but this is impossible since $||e_i -e_j| =\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: How do you get the first line of your proof?

Comment: Please look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163500/an-application-of-riesz-lemma and here : http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/riesz_lemma.pdf