# Sequences in Hilbert spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces

We have a sequence $(x_{n})_{n=1}^\infty$ in a Hilbert space $H$ and we know that:

1. for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ holds $\|x_{n}\|\le1$
2. for every $m\ne n$ holds $\|x_{n}-x_{m}\|\ge r > 0$

How I can show that $r \le \sqrt2$ ?

Comment: I thought a bounded sequence must have a convergent subsequence...

Comment: If the vectors form an orthogonal set, then square, throw away the inner product term and take the square root again. Otherwise, I don't know - it does look like the Riesz-Lemma though, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163500/an-application-of-riesz-lemma

Comment: @Kenny, so $H$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Use the triangle inequality.

Comment: @KennyLau Not necessarily in infinite-dimensional spaces. Consider the canonical vectors $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $\ell^2$. It is bounded but $\|e_m - e_n\| = \sqrt{2}$ for $m \ne n$.

Comment: @kimchilover: the assertion is not true in finite-dimensional spaces, so I fail to see how your suggestion might work.

Comment: @KennyLau. That is true in $\Bbb R^n$. It is not true in Hilbert space

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I know. I don't need three people telling me the same thing.

Comment: @KennyLau. Sorry. I didn't see the others.

Answer (score 7):

Notice that whenever $m \neq n$, we have

$$ r^2 \leq \|x_n - x_m\|^2 \leq 2 - 2\operatorname{Re} \langle x_m, x_n \rangle
\quad \Rightarrow \quad
2\operatorname{Re} \langle x_m, x_n \rangle \leq 2 - r^2. \tag{*}$$

Then for any positive integer $N \geq 2$,

\begin{align*}
0
\leq \left\| \sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n \right\|^2
&= \sum_{m,n = 1}^{N} \langle x_m, x_n \rangle \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{N} \langle x_n, x_n \rangle + \sum_{1 \leq m < n \leq N} 2 \operatorname{Re}\langle x_m, x_n \rangle \\
&\stackrel{(*)}{\leq} N + \frac{N(N-1)}{2}(2-r^2).
\end{align*}

So it follows that $ 2 - r^2 \geq -\frac{2}{N-1} $ and letting $N \to \infty$ yields the desired claim.

Answer (score 0):

The unit ball $B$ of a Hilbert space is weakly sequentially compact so the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ has a weakly-convergent subsequence with limit in $B$.

WLOG we can assume that $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ weakly. Then for every $m\ne n$ we have
$$r^2 \leq \|x_n - x_m\|^2 \leq 2 - 2\operatorname{Re} \langle x_m, x_n \rangle \xrightarrow{m,n\to\infty} 2-\|x\|^2 \le 2$$
so $r \le \sqrt{2}$.