# Does every infinite-dimensional Banach space admit an "almost orthonormal" infinite set?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, orthonormal

Every infinite-dimensional Hilbert space admits an orthonormal basis. The basis has the three properties:

1. The elements are linearly independent
2. All elements have length $1$.
3. The pairs between any pair is $\sqrt 2$.

In a general Banach space define a set $S$ to be *almost orthonormal* to mean the following:

1. The elements of $S$ are linearly independent
2. There exists $E,\epsilon >0$ such that $E \ge \|s\| \ge \epsilon $ for all $s \in S$.
3. There exists $\delta >0$ such that $\|s_1-s_2\| \ge \delta$ for all $s_1,s_2 \in S$.

Does every Banach space contain an infinite almost orthonormal set?

Comment: Do you want $\|s\|\leq \epsilon$? Because otherwise this condition is very easy (choose linearly independent elements $e_n$, rescale so that $\|e_n\|=n$ and then condition 3 is automatic).

Comment: @s.harp You are right. I also want the elements to have length bounded from above. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like s job for Riesz's lemma.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163500/an-application-of-riesz-lemma).